# Show working day and weekend using case in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I have a query like this:

```
select 
    F_Po_Date, 
    DATENAME (Weekday, F_Po_Date) as Name,
    (case when Name = 'Saturday or Sunday' then 'Weekend' else "Working" end) as 'OFfdays' 
from 
    T_assets
```

I am showing all the days, if date is Saturday or Sunday, the next column I want to show as **weekend**, otherwise I want to show **working**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You should use case this way

```
   select F_Po_Date
  , DATENAME(Weekday,F_Po_Date) as Name
  , case when DATENAME(Weekday,F_Po_Date) IN  ('Saturday', 'Sunday' ) 
          then 'Weekend' 
          else "Working" end  as OFfdays 
  from T_assets
```

foe eval several condition you should use IN clause

or for few option you could use OR

```
   select F_Po_Date
  , DATENAME(Weekday,F_Po_Date) as Name
  , case when DATENAME(Weekday,F_Po_Date) = 'Saturday' 
                OR DATENAME(Weekday,F_Po_Date) = 'Sunday' ) 
          then 'Weekend' 
          else "Working" end  as OFfdays 
  from T_assets
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `datepart()` and `datename()` can return different values depending on internationalization settings.

I would recommend `format()` for this, because you can guarantee that the results work *regardless of server settings*:

```
select F_Po_Date, 
       format(F_Po_Date, 'dddd', 'en-us') AS Name,
       (case when format(F_Po_Date, 'ddd', 'en-us') in ('Sat', 'Sun') 
             then 'Weekend' else 'Working'
        end) as OFfdays
from T_assets;
```

Also, use single quotes for string (and date constants).  Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  In fact, don't even both escaping the aliases if escape characters are not needed.